# Open External Links inside Webview

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, android-webview

I want to open a `webview` with `POST` data. So I am doing this:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.dashboard);
String url = "http://www.example.test";
String postData = "json=" + JSON;
webView.postUrl(url, postData.getBytes());
```

So now when I launch this `webview`, clicking on links open a default browser of device, is there any way to stick to `webview` for opening links?
I researched but all of them are for `GET` requests.

Comment: `I researched but all of them are for GET requests.` it does not matter, it will work the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the solution it is pretty much same for both `GET` and `POST` requests.

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.dashboard);

    String url = "http://www.example.test";
    String postData = "json=" + JSON;

    webView.postUrl(url,postData.getBytes());

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView viewx, String urlx) {
            viewx.loadUrl(urlx);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it in Kotlin:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            myWebView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
                    view: WebView,
                    request: WebResourceRequest
                ): Boolean {
                    view.loadUrl(request.url.toString())
                    return false
                }
            }
        } else {
            myWebView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {
                    view?.loadUrl(url.toString())
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
```